# How get the lastIndexof with swift 2.0

Tags: swift

I have tried to implement a method lastIndexOf. My code

```
extension String {
    var length:Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }

    func indexOf(target: String) -> Int? {

        let range = (self as NSString).rangeOfString(target)

        guard range.toRange() != nil else {
            return nil
        }

        return range.location

    }
    func lastIndexOf(target: String) -> Int? {

        let range = (self as NSString).rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.BackwardsSearch)

        guard range.toRange() != nil else {
            return nil
        }

        return self.length - range.location - 1

    }
}
```

IndexOf returns me 45

"11055010155031e146145257690278f95004eca3d9ea110038da71507".indexOf("1003")

but lastIndexOf 11

"11055010155031e146145257690278f95004eca3d9ea110038da71507".lastIndexOf("1003")

I am not sure where is my error

Thank for any help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `lastIndexOf()` method returns 11 because

```
return self.length - range.location - 1
```

computes the offset from the location where the substring was found
to the last character of the string, in your case `57 - 45 - 1 = 11`.
If you change the return statement to

```
return range.location
```

then you will get `45` for both calls because the substring "1003"
occurs only once in the larger string.

Note that you can compute the offsets without using `NSString`/`NSRange`:

```
extension String {
    func indexOf(target: String) -> Int? {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(target) {
            return startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func lastIndexOf(target: String) -> Int? {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(target, options: .BackwardsSearch) {
            return startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This also works better for strings with characters outside of the
"Basic Multilingual Plane" such as Emojis or "flags". Examples are

```
"abcdef".indexOf("d")
```

where your method returns `5` instead of `4` or

```
"abcdef".indexOf("d")
```

where your method returns `7` instead of `4`.

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension String {
    func index(of target: String) -> Int? {
        if let range = self.range(of: target) {
            return characters.distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func lastIndex(of target: String) -> Int? {
        if let range = self.range(of: target, options: .backwards) {
            return characters.distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```